# Foreign characters in Python 3.2

Tags: python, string, python-3.x

I'm writing a program in Python 3.2 that needs to be able to detect if a string contains the foreign characters "å, ä, ö". I have written the following piece of code:

```
# This Python file uses the following encoding: utf-8

name = input('Give your name: ')

if ('å' in name) or ('ä' in name) or ('ö' in name):
   print('Foreign characters found')
```

However, if I enter for instance "Åke", the program still doesn't execute the print-command. Any ideas of why this is the case? Or do you have any other ideas of how I can detect the characters "å, ä, ö" in a given string?

Comment: You are aware that "å" and "Å" are two different characters?

Comment: use `name = input('Give your name: ').lower()`

Comment: Does your terminal use UTF-8?

Comment: @SvenMarnach: I suppose that I could fix that by making all the characters lowercase, just as BrtH suggested.

Comment: @chepner: I must admit that I don't really know, I'm quite new to this. I'm using a MacBookPro.

Comment: So does it work if you make it lowercase, or does it still not execute the print?

Comment: What does `print(repr(name))` print after entering "Åke"?

Comment: What's the output of `print(sys.stdin.encoding)`?

Comment: @SvenMarnach: print repr(name) gives '√Öke'

Comment: @SvenMarnach: And I'm unable to compile the program when writing `print(sys.stdin.encoding)` since Ecplise (which I am using) says that "sys is an undefined variable"

Comment: You need to `import sys` to make this work.

Comment: @SvenMarnach: Ok, no it worked. The output of the command 'print(sys.stdin.encoding)` is `utf-8`

Comment: Are you shure that `# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-` is at the top of your file, or do you just _think_ that your file is utf-8?

Comment: And what do you think of my answer, because if that is what you want, we don't even **have** to solve this problem.

Comment: @SvenMarnach: The `repr(name)` does not work the same in Python 3 as it worked in Python 2. The `ascii(name)` must be used for the purpose instead.

Answer (score 1):

You are now just checking for those three characters, and although this doesn't answer your question, this might be a better method to check for foreign characters:

```
try:
    name.encode('ascii')
except UnicodeError:
    print('Foreign characters found')
```

Note: tested in python 2.7, but I assume it should work in 3.2 too.

Comment: `except UnicodeError:` is equivalent - UnicodeEncodeError and UnicodeDecodeError are subclasses of UnicodeError.

Comment: @ThomasK, Ok, I will trust you on that, I'm not such an unicode expert :P